# Remove code from content type news article

Tags: 7

Is there anyway to remove the code snippets from the content news article. facebook is pulling in the teaser text for the content which is correct but it is displaying unwanted code (as you can see in the screenshot).[image]

thanks for your help!

Comment: Change the text format to something with `_html` in it...

Comment: In the Sructure -> Content Type -> News -> manage display tab change the "Format" to "Plain Text".

Comment: the text processing is currently set as 'plain text'

Comment: Yep that's the problem @Aaron. HTML != plain text. You need to pick a format that will render HTML. The advice above is wrong, you need to change it _away_ from plain text, not to plain text

Comment: which version of drupal are you using?